# Layer leaf nodes replicated across all tree nodes using GeoExt?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

This is going on with GeoExt 1.1 and OpenLayers 2.12. I need to build a layer tree dynamically, with layers and nodes that are only known at run time. The snippets I show below correctly create a layer tree with several nodes and adds the layers node leafs. The problem is that though each layer is assigned to a single tree node, it is then shown under each and every tree node created.

During init the tree and its root are set up:

```
  treeRoot = new Ext.tree.TreeNode
  ({
      text        : 'Project',
      id          : '0',
      leaf        :false,
      expandable  : true,
      expanded    : true
  });

  layerTree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel
  ({
    title: 'Map Layers',
    region: "west",
    width: 200,
    collapsible: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    enableDD: true,
    plugins:
    [{
      ptype: "gx_treenodecomponent"
    }],
    loader:
    {
      applyLoader: false,
      uiProviders:
      {
        "custom_ui": LayerNodeUI
      }
    },
    root: treeRoot,
    rootVisible: false,
    lines: false
  });
```

Later on new tree nodes can be added according to a tag, and kept in an array:

```
if(treeNodes[tag] == null)
{
    treeNodes[tag] = new GeoExt.tree.OverlayLayerContainer
    ({
            text: tag,
            leaf: false,
            expanded: true
    });
    treeRoot.appendChild(treeNodes[tag]);
}
```

Layers are added to the map and to a specific tree node:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(title, serviceURL, params, options);
leftMap.addLayer(layer);
layer.events.register("visibilitychanged", this, toggleLayer);

var newNode = new GeoExt.tree.LayerNode(
{
    text: title,
    layer: layerName,
    leaf: true,
    checked: false,
    children: [],
    nodeType: "gx_layer"
});
treeNodes[tag].appendChild(newNode);
```

But then each layer appears several times, once under each tree node.

Why is it happening this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good deal of fuddling around I found out was wrong:

1. OverlayLayerContainer includes all layers in the OpenLayers.Map object, I had to replace it by a regular Ext TreeNode:

   `WebGIS.treeNodes[tag] = new Ext.tree.TreeNode`
2. The Layer node was being initialised with the layer name instead of the OpeanLayers.Layer object. This how it should like:

   `var newNode = new GeoExt.tree.LayerNode
   ({
       text: title,
       layer: layer,
       leaf: true,
       checked: false,
       children: [],
       nodeType: "gx_layer"
   });`